# MongoDB - Return matched sub-document from an array based on condition

Tags: mongodb

Imagine a document like below -

I want to return the PART along with
Input's would be language say "ENG" or "FRA" or "GER"

Document-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56a5337f19d312a4156a3625"),
    "PartId" : "Part1",
    "Name" : "Name",
    "active" : "true",
    "attribute1" : "value1",
    "attribute2" : "value2",
    "LanguageData":[ 
        {
            "Language" : "ENG",
            "description" : "PARt1- English",
            "default" : "true"
        }, 
        {
            "Language" : "FRA",
            "description" : "Part1 in french",
            "supported" : "true"
        }, 
        {
            "Language" : "GER",
            "description" : "Part1 In German",
            "supported" : "false"
        }
    ]
}
```

If input is "ENG"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56a5337f19d312a4156a3625"),
    "PartId" : "Part1",
    "Name" : "Name",
    "active" : "true",
    "attribute1" : "value1",
    "attribute2" : "value2",
    "LanguageData":[ 
        {
            "Language" : "ENG",
            "description" : "PARt1- English",
            "default" : "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

If input is "GER" the out put should not return this document as "supported is false"

```
{}
```

If input is say "CHN" then default should be returned -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56a5337f19d312a4156a3625"),
    "PartId" : "Part1",
    "Name" : "Name",
    "active" : "true",
    "attribute1" : "value1",
    "attribute2" : "value2",
    "LanguageData":[ 
        {
            "Language" : "ENG",
            "description" : "PARt1- English",
            "default" : "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not able to return sub document based on the conditions

Only the subdocument from array should be returned based on below conditions

1) So if language is present, then return that sub document.

2) If Sub-Document is not present always return default.

3) If Sub Document is present and not supported , do not return the whole document

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Can I use condition's in elemMatch during projection, slect specific language if present else select Default if language is not present?

Answer (score 2):

To query the subdocument, you can do that through [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)

```
db.document.aggregate([
    {$match: {'LanguageData.Language': 'GER'}},
    {$project: {
        LanguageData: {$filter: {
            input: '$LanguageData',
            as: 'LanguageData',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$LanguageData.Language', 'GER']}
        }}
    }}
])
```

For return the default data, the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) could do that

```
db.document.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$LanguageData'}, 
    {$match: {'LanguageData.Language': 'GER'}}, 
    {$project: 
       {LanguageData: 
          {Language: {$ifNull: ['$LanguageData.Language', 'CHN']}, 
           description: {$ifNull: ['$LanguageData.description', 'default description']}}}}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I cannot match default rule when some language is not present "ZHN" is not present in the array of languages.

Comment: @AlokRagate, I think `$ifNull` may meet your requirement to return the default value.

Comment: Thanks for the response , Although I am getting the below error-uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$filter'",
 "code" : 15999,
 "ok" : 0
}

Comment: @AlokRagate, I just give you some sample codes here, for more details of the aggregation parameter, please go to the mongodb site....

Comment: @AlokRagate, the `$filter` is added after version 3.2, what the version of mongo are you using?

Comment: The below fails to return data when there is no matchin Language, and I would still want to return the default sub documnet.      db.TestTopics.aggregate([
      { $unwind : "$LanguageData" },
      { $match: { "LanguageData.language": 'GER' }},
      {
         $project: {
            LanguageData: { $ifNull: ["$description", "Unspecified"]}
         }
      }
]);